# Why does insert script using cx_Oracle hangs

Tags: python, oracle

I'm new to Python, using cx_Oracle.execute to insert a row into a table.

I prepare the `insert` statement, which works on SQL developer.

`print` statements prior to the execute indicate it hangs on execute. 
A simple `select` statement works using the same package.

- Python version is 2.7
- Oracle version is 11g
- cx_Oracle version is 5.2.1
- Eclipse is 4.4.2
- Pydev is 4.5.5

I have tried this on Anaconda as well, same result.

```
import cx_Oracle

Connection = cx_Oracle.connect('connectioninfo')
cursor = connection.cursor()
print(cx_Oracle.__file__) 
print(cx_Oracle._version)

sql1 = "insert into date_dim(dateid) values (20170523)"
print(sql1)
cursor.execute(sql1) # hangs here 
count = cursor.rowcount 

print(count)
connection.commit() # Never gets to this statement        
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 14):

It looks like I had another session open on Sql Developer to test the insert script where I never run a Commit so when I run the Python insert script, somehow it was hanging waiting for the other commit to be issued so it can issue its own commit which was the next line in the code but the other commit was never issued in Sql Developer! As soon as I run a commit in Sql Developer, Python completed the insert. What do you know? Posted my first question on Stackoverflow and my first answer to my first question, that's gotta be a first!

Comment: This is fantastic. I did the same mistake and was stuck to it for half a day. Very useful post.

Comment: Me too. This post is really helpful